# if I don't print the value of a function parameter its convert to equal zero

Tags: c++

I think it's a bug or I don't know but the following code prints zero...

```
double sinWave(double dAmplitude, double dFrequency, double dTime) {
    std::cout << dFrequency;    
    return dAmplitude*sin(HzToRad(dFrequency)*dTime);

}

auto soundWave(double dAmplitude, double dFrequency) {
    return [&](double x) { return sinWave(dAmplitude, dFrequency, x); };    
}
```

and here if a print the dFrequency value in soundWave function its contains the correct value. Can somebody answer me for why it's happening

```
double sinWave(double dAmplitude, double dFrequency, double dTime) {
    std::cout << dFrequency <<"\n";
    return dAmplitude*sin(HzToRad(dFrequency)*dTime);
}

auto soundWave(double dAmplitude, double dFrequency) {
    std::cout << dFrequency << "\n";
    return [&](double x) { return sinWave(dAmplitude, dFrequency, x); };    
}
```

And here is mi main function...

```
int main() {
    auto sound = soundWave(1, octaveOf(note<B>::mFrequency, 3));
    sound(1);
    // for(double t = 0.0; t < 1000.0; t+=0.0001){
    //     std::cout << "Frequency: " << sound(1) << "\n";
    //     Beep(sound(t), 1);
    // }
}
```

Where note::mFrequency is 30.87Hz and octaveOf have the next code:

```
constexpr double octaveOf(double dFrecquency, int n) {
    return dFrecquency*pow(2,n);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that your lambda captures by reference.  In `soundWave` both `dAmplitude` and `dFrequency` are scoped to the life of the function so when you capture them by reference and return the lambda, the lambda is referring to objects that no longer exist and using them is undefined behavior.

What you need to do is capture by value, so the lambda gets its own copy of the function parameters, and those will live for the life of the lambda.  Changing `soundWave` to

```
auto soundWave(double dAmplitude, double dFrequency) {
    return [=](double x) { return sinWave(dAmplitude, dFrequency, x); };   
    //      ^ = means capture by value (make a copy)
}
```

will fix the problem.